# Jasmine Test case for close button

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

It's my first time to write test case.

I want to write test case for `close` method which will hide the banner and also it will set a cookie so that when user visits the site for the second time it won't appear again.

I wanted to cover the following scenarios

- should call the `close` method when clicked on the button
- mat-card should have been hidden after `close` method is called
- Cookie should have been created.

Please guide me.

Below is my code

**Component**

```
export class APComponent {

  private cookie: any;
  private cpBanner: boolean;

  constructor(
    private cookieService: CookieService) {
    this.cookie = this.cookieService.get('CP_BANNER');
    this.cpBanner = this.cookie ? false : true;
  }

  close() {
    this.cpBanner = false;
    this.cookieService.put( 'CP_BANNER', 'true' );
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-card *ngIf="apBanner"><mat-card-actions>
    <mat-icon name="cross" cropped="cropped" (click)="close()"></mat-icon>
  </mat-card-actions></mat-card>
```

**My Spec.ts**

```
describe('APComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<APComponent>;
    let component: APComponent;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
            declarations: [ APComponent ],
            imports: [CommonModule, CookieModule.forRoot()],

        });
        TestBed.compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(APComponent);
    });

    it('should create the app', async(() => {
        const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it('should close the banner', async(() => {

    }));

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need to cover in terms of unit testing the `close` method.Testing that it is called when a button is clicked is more suited for functionality testing in the e2e tests.

The first test checks that it does set the instance variable to false. To make sure that's the case we manually set the variable to true before calling close().

```
it('should close the banner', async(() => {
  // Arrange
  const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  app.cpBanner = true;

  // Act
  app.close();

  // Assert
  expect(app.cpBanner).toBe(false);
}));
```

The second test checks that it calls a service to create the cookie. The close method doesn't actually create the cookie after all. Testing the actual creation of cookies should in the spec file of the CookieService. To assert that a method has been called you use Jasmine [spies](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/your_first_suite#section-Spies). So we first get a handle of the service that's been injected to the app and spy on its put method.

Note: I could not verify that the code below works because I don't have the service but it should at least demonstrate the logic.

```
it('should call the cookie service to create the cookie', async(() => {
  // Arrange
  const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  const cookieService = fixture.TestBed.get(CookieService);
  spyOn(cookieService, 'put');

  // Act
  app.close();

  // Assert
  expect(cookieService.put).toHaveBeenCalledWith('CP_BANNER', 'true');
}));
```